# JS: How to make my code wait until this function has returned?

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, promise, react-native-permissions

I have the following code in my React Native app for checking if permission is granted for a camera on Android:

```
function hasAndroidPermission() {
    checkPermission('camera')
        .then(res => {
            if (res === RESULTS.DENIED) {
                requestPermission('camera')
                    .then(res => {
                        if (res === RESULTS.DENIED) {
                            return false
                        } else {
                            return true
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        // console.log(err)
                    })
            } else {
                return true
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // console.log(err)
        })
}
```

I want to execute some other code depending on the result of `hasAndroidPermission()`. I tried this (in an async function):

```
let androidPermission = await hasAndroidPermission()
if (androidPermission) ...
```

The code executes the `if` block before `hasAndroidPermission()` has returned. How can I make it wait?

Comment: you should return promise and subscribe to it with then, and inside that check the values. ```return checkPermission...```

Comment: `return checkPermission.then(...)`. Add the `return` ...

Answer (score 1):

You should use async/await and make `hasAndroidPermission` an async function:

```
async function hasAndroidPermission() {
    const res = await checkPermission('camera')
    if (res === RESULTS.DENIED) {
        const res = await requestPermission('camera')
        if (res === RESULTS.DENIED) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the return statement before your `checkPermission()` and `requestPermission()`call

Comment: Not only that one